# Windows8 drops network connection shortly after boot (but works if I wait)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, internet-connection, tcp

I have a test lab which runs tests against `Windows8` machine, more specifically a `Pytest` project which generates `TCP` traffic from my `Ubuntu` machine to `Windows8` machine, and from the `Windows8` machine back to the `Ubuntu`. Then I verify certain details about the traffic in my tests.

Before the tests are run, I boot the `Windows8` machine, establish SSH connection to it from the `Ubuntu` and start running the tests as soon as the machine is up and SSH is established.

The tests also establish `asyncio` sockets with the `Windows` machine (there's other code loaded into the Windows machine prior to tests which interacts back with the tests in order to create traffic).

Completely randomly, during ~50% of runs all the connections drop from `Windows` side, before tests start run or during the very first tests.

After trying nearly anything, I decided to put a `time.sleep` of a few minutes right before tests start to run and it actually worked (connection never drops).

I suspect that some process or service during `Windows8` boot needs more time to stabilize before handling traffic but I can't figure it out because I have a similar setup for other Windows versions and it never happens, only `Windows8` drops traffic.

What I've tried so far:

- Turn off firewall (all profiles)
- Disable Windows Defender (I still see it in Task Manager and can't kill it but in settings it shows as disabled)
- Disabled sleep for Windows
- Set allowed number of parallel TCP connections (in registry) to be unlimited

None of the above seemed to help, **only waiting for a few minutes after boot**.
What could be the issue ?

Comment: Do you mean that all the connection have succeeded, but when heavy traffic started the connection dropped? Do you see any useful messages in the Event Viewer? Search the computer for any `.dmp` files with matching dates.

Comment: @harrymc Heavy traffic didn't take place because connection drops during the very first tests (which produce very minimal traffic, 1 TCP message per test). Will look for the .dmp files and update